# Why I can't enable custom systemd service to start uWSGI?

Tags: 15.04, services, systemd

I created a Django project with virtualenv. The site will be deployed with `nginx` and `uwsgi`. I want to enable `uwsgi` as systemd service. I've created this:

```
[Unit]                                                                                                                                                          
Description=uWSGI Emperor at mysite                                                                                                                             
After=syslog.target                                                                                                                                             

[Service]                                                                                                                                                       
ExecStart=/home/user/Django/bin/uwsgi --ini /srv/mysite.com/deploy/uwsgi/mysite.ini                                                                             
Restart=always                                                                                                                                                  
KillSignals=SIGQUIT                                                                                                                                             
Type=notify                                                                                                                                                     
StandardError=syslog                                                                                                                                            
NotifyAccess=all                                                                                                                                                

[Install]                                                                                                                                                       
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I put the service file in `/srv/mysite.com/deploy/uwsgi/mysite.service` and created symlink that point to it in `/etc/systemd/system/mysite.service`.

I can start it with:

```
systemctl start mysite.service
```

But, I can't enable it:

```
systemctl start mysite.service
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

What did I do wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

The service file is specified in your config as:

```
/srv/mysite.com/deploy/uwsgi/mysite.ini
```

Which doesn't match with:

```
/srv/mysite.com/deploy/uwsgi/mysite.service
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't `enable` symlinked services. You need to copy the original service file to the `/etc/systemd/system/` instead

Comment: Just want to point out that this is wrong and a symlink is absolutely valid. In fact symlinks are what `systemctl` does on `enable`.

Comment: @IgnacioLago Oh, means that the bug was fixed! Great news